# Hyperledger fabric adding new orderer in existing setup getting error: x509: ECDSA verification failure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to add a new orderer in existing hyperledger fabric setup, I have generated crypto materials for new orderer and also got the updated configuration block(updated with orderer2 tls cerificate), but when I'm running peer channel update command then I'm getting following error:

```
2021-06-21 17:56:11.396 IST [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'system-channel': consensus metadata update for channel config update is invalid: invalid new config metadata: verifying tls client cert with serial number 263873995186984697997414029375430958056: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "tlsca.example.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an order is a network-level operation and it requires a signature from  Organization Admins for update transaction before updating the network configuration ( the number of signatures depends on the policy for network-level operations and the number of orgs you have on your network topology ).